# sed unterminated s command in vagrant only

Tags: sed, vagrant

I have weird `sed` behaviour when using sed within a Vagrant provisioning script.

I need to modify a line of the default mongod.conf file for a mongo DB, the following sed command works fine when launched from a standard command line:

```
sudo sed -i "s/#security:/security:\n  authorization: enabled/g" /etc/mongod.conf
```

Or when wrapped inside of a shell script it works also:

```
#!/bin/sh    
sudo sed -i "s/#security:/security:\n  authorization: enabled/g" /etc/mongod.conf
```

But if I use the same command inside a vagrant provisioner script:

```
@mongo_security_and_user_setup = <<SCRIPT
    sudo sed -i "s/#security:/security:\n  authorization: enabled/g" /etc/mongod.conf
SCRIPT
```

I get the error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 25: unterminated `s' command

I could of course create a shell script and run it from the provisioner thus bypassing the problem, but I would like to know why this is failing.

I know it is caused when I add the `\n` to the command, because without `\n` it runs as expected in the Vagrant provisioner.  Unfortunately I need the carriage return for the new config to work correctly.

Comment: `sed` assumes that the script (`s/#security:/security:\n  authorization: enabled/g`) ends after the 25th character. To limit the problem, I would try to remove `\n` in the first step.

Comment: I need \n, I can't remove it, the problem is the \n as I mention in the question

Comment: I'm guessing Vagrant expands `\n` for you. You have to figure out how to disable or escape that.

Comment: Try to replace `\n` with `\x0a`.

Comment: Yep the answer is to double escape actually, I've just sussed it out

Comment: So \\n works, weird behaviour but that seems to solve it

Comment: The answer is a duplicate you're quite the question isn't though, as I am not appending anything

Comment: If the duplicate's *answer* helped you, please accept it. Your question will still remain visible as a signpost for others with this problem.

Comment: It didn't I sussed it out myself.  I honesty don't mind, but I didn't find the other answer, so this might be useful to somebody.  At this point it's no longer for me.